# Libgdx AssetsManager - Sounds Loaded but "Not Loaded Error"?

Tags: java, android, audio, libgdx

When using LibGDX's AssetsManager, I've implement an AssetsManager for managing Sounds, and made it global. The files are all located within

```
../data/sounds/.*
(example: ../data/sounds/buttons/buttonl.mp3)
```

Then I load sound files into the manager, and then include some code to play those sounds. Code below:

```
public final class Sounds {
    private static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> entries = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
    private static HashMap<String, String> currentPackage = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public static Sound sound;

    public Sounds() {
        addPath(
            "Main", 
            "bgm", "data/sounds/main/title.mp3",
            "buttonl", "data/sounds/buttons/buttonl.mp3",
            "buttonh", "data/sounds/buttons/buttonh.mp3");

        //... More paths with more sound assets
    }

    public static boolean addPath(String packageName, String... args) {
        if(!entries.containsKey(packageName)) {
            entries.put(packageName, new HashMap<String, String>());
            for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i ++)
                entries.get(packageName).put(args[i], args[++i]);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void loadSoundAssets(String packageName) {
        for(String str : entries.get(packageName).values())
            s_manager.load(str, Sound.class);
        s_manager.finishLoading();
    }

    public static boolean play(String file) {
        if(currentPackage.containsKey(file)) {
            sound = s_manager.get(file, Sound.class);
            sound.play();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

After creating the Sound class in a higher class with

```
public class Game implements ApplicationListener{
    public Sounds gameSounds = new Sounds();

    public Screen currentScreen = new MainMenuScreen();
    //... More class variables and methods

    public void render() {
        currentScreen.update();
    }
}
```

The problem comes when I call

```
public class MainScreen() extends Screen {
    public MainScreen() {
        Sounds.loadSoundAssets("Main");
        //... More constructor variables and methods
    }
    //... Class variables and methods

    public void update() {
        if(s_manager.update()) {
            if(play.getBoundingRectangle().contains(x, y))
                Sounds.play("buttonl");
        }
    }
}
```

s_manager.update() returns true, but then it tries to play the sound file "buttonl" and throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Asset not loaded: buttonh
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.get(AssetManager.java:121)
    at device.sounds.Sounds.play(Sounds.java:146)
    at game.screens.MainMenuScreen.update(MainMenuScreen.java:63)
    at menu.StateManager.render(StateManager.java:89)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:190)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)
```

How should I be using the AssetsManager to fix this loading/playing problem? I want to use the AssetsManager, but currently, my solution is to use

```
sound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal(currentPackage.get(file)));
```

Comment: You do call loadSoundAssets(), correct? Just making sure.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I forgot that line of code. It is placed in the MainScreen class. I have updated the above code to show where loadSoundAssets(String) is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that in your play method, you are calling AssetManager.get on the key rather than its value in currentPackage. I think a correct play method would be:

```
public static boolean play(String file) {
    if(currentPackage.containsKey(file)) {
        sound = s_manager.get(currentPackage.get(file), Sound.class);
        sound.play();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```