# libgdx path to file when using assetManager.load();

Tags: java, android, libgdx, assets

I found this solution to load my sounds, but it always writes "file not loaded". eatSound.wav is located in the assets folder. Am I using the correct path to eatSound? How can I know what is the correct path?

```
private AssetManager assetManager;

public SoundManager(){
        assetManager = new AssetManager();
        assetManager.load("eatSound.wav",Sound.class);
}

public boolean startMusic() {
    if(assetManager.isLoaded("eatSound.wav")) {
   Sound sound= assetManager.get("eatSound.wav", Sound.class);
   sound.play();

    }else {
        System.out.println("not loaded yet");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I use

```
Sound sound = new Sound(Gdx.files.internal("eatSound.wav")); 
sound.play();
```

It starts to work correctly after 10/20 times I call play() method. So I have decided to use assetManager. But I am not sure if I am using the correct file path for my sound.

Comment: This is typical in the case of `Sound` objects. Try looking at question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830760/libgdx-assetsmanager-sounds-loaded-but-not-loaded-error?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is that loading an asset might take a while...a few milliseconds, depending on the size of the asset, the device resources, etc. So, this line...

```
assetManager.load("eatSound.wav",Sound.class);
```

could lag a bit and if you attempt to call your `startMusic()` method immediately after initializing the class you will very likely encounter that the asset haven't finished loading. Here's an example...

```
SoundManager sm = new SoundManager();
sm.startMusic();
```

running this will probably never play the sound because you're not allowing enough time for the asset to load fully. I'll suggest initializing the `SoundManager` class somewhere else (in advanced) or add a delay between the initialization and the call to `startMusic`

Comment: I have already initialize SoundManager in my gameScreen and i use startMusic() when my character overlaps some objects, but every time i get "not loaded yet". Is there any way to chceck what is correct path to my Sounds ?

Answer (score 0):

My sound Manager didn't work because i havent called assetManager.update() in render method.